# Spring WebClient returns Lambda instead of Data from Rest Service

Tags: spring, web

I am calling a Rest Service with a WebClient but I only get a response back which is the following:

```
Object is reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber@4681c175
```

I was hoping to get a JSON string back. When I call the service with a RestTemplate I get the expected JSON string back. Here is the code I use to make the call that returns the Lambda object back:

```
    Object objj= WebClient.create("http://localhost/printer-service/jobs")
        .get()   
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .flatMapMany(cr -> cr.bodyToFlux(String.class))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
         System.out.println("Object is "+objj);
```

Why is this call not returning the JSON string?

Comment: your response would have printed as part of ```.subscribe(System.out::println);```. If you need ```Object objj``` then you need to call ```.block``` which will make it a blocking behaviour and it deviates from what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No response except the Lambda is printed.  My goal was to process the response in the subscriber but no intelligible response comes back just the Lambda object as I've indicated already. And you mean blockFirst(), I suppose.

Comment: can you confirm whats the response of this ```http://localhost/printer-service/jobs```

Comment: It looks like the publisher is not emitting any element. Add debug logs to find out and share the logs to get help. Also make sure ```http://localhost/printer-service/jobs``` returning the desired response.